# How to get the html text in python using selenium?

Tags: python, list, loops, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using python's selenium and trying extract the text into a list or dataframe. Iam trying get the text"M" from class="flex">M. Put this and another item into a dataframe and then loop and do again adding rows to a dataframe.

```
elm_result1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[flex ng-bind='LB.record.SEX_CD']")
print("Total results: ", elm_result1.text)
```

HTML

```
<span flex-gt-sm="" layout="row" class="layout-row flex-gt-sm">
    <span class="summaryLabel shorterLabel">Gender</span>
    <span flex="" ng-bind="LB.record.SEX_CD" class="flex">M</span>
</span>
```

and another similar structure

```
<span flex="" ng-bind="(LB.record.FIRST_NAME)" class="flex">A</span>
```

Error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below css.

```
elm_result1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.flex[ng-bind='LB.record.SEX_CD']")
print("Total results: ", elm_result1.text)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Use this css `span.flex[ng-bind^='(latestBene.record.BRTH_DT ']`

Comment: how can I fix this code and write to a csv file? its currently looping through but not append after each input is recorded. The list comes out [] blank.

Comment: Can you please post a new question, just don't want the things get complicated and messed up by answering a different question here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57368284/in-python-using-selenium-how-do-i-output-this-data-to-a-csv-file-with-headers

Comment: Can you take a look at this question thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59433697/using-selenium-in-python-how-do-i-click-a-link-that-is-different-for-each-item

Comment: How can i click on this link... <td class="o-hidden to-ellipsis">
                            <a href="w/edit/5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9" class="workspace_click_handler">
                                Secure File Transfer - USA
                            </a><a class="show-on-hover hidden-xs description-popover" data-original-title="Description" data-desc-content="Secure file transfer zone for customers in the USA" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-info f-20"></i>
                                </a></td>

Comment: I tried this WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.CSS_SELECTOR(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#wl-open-5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9")).click()

Comment: That's not locator, try with `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.CSS_SELECTOR(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[href='wl-open-5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9']")).click() `

Comment: I get ...AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions' has no attribute 'CSS_SELECTOR'

Comment: <tr class="show-on-hover-parent list-row-hover workspace-list-row" data-href="/w/edit/5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9/" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <td class="o-hidden to-ellipsis">
                            <a href="w/edit/5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9" class="workspace_click_handler">
                                Secure File Transfer - USA
                            </a><a class="show-on-hover hidden-xs description-popover" data-original-title="Description" data-desc-content="Secure file transfer zone for customers in the USA"

Comment: when I try That's not locator, try with WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.CSS_SELECTOR(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[href='wl-open-5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9']")).click(). I get AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions' has no attribute 'CSS_SELECTOR'

Comment: My bad, I haven't paid attention to that part `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[href='wl-open-5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9']")).click()`

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-b52fd22451df> in <module>
     21 
     22 
---> 23 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[href='wl-open-5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9']")).click()

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: adding a extra () around By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[href='wl-open-5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9']"... ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-53703d06aadc> in <module>
     21 
     22 
---> 23 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[href='wl-open-5bb4d0205a4f9e384ea88ba9']"))).click()
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message: