# How do I output data to a CSV file with headers?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, dataframe, writer

I want to output this data to a csv file. Currently, it's not appending anything when getting to the `css_selector` the text is not being appended. I want to append it to a list, then in a dataframe and then to a csv file.

```
list1=[]
for i, j in df1.iterrows():
    name = j[1]
    id1 = j[2]
    sleep(3)
    BI_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 
    10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'BI')))
    BI_box.send_keys(id1)

    Last_Name_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 
    10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'last')))
    Last_Name_box.send_keys(name)

    Sea= WebDriverWait(driver, 
    10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'srch')))
    Sea.click()
    try:
        elm_result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.flex[ng- 
        bind='(lbecord.F)']").text
        list1.append(elm_result)
        print(elm_result)
        print(list1)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        elm_result4 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.flex[ng- 
        bind^='(la.record.B_DT ']").text
        list1.append(elm_result4)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        elm_result12 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[ng- 
        bind='row.RISK_IND']").text
        list1.append(elm_result12)
    except:
        pass
    sleep(2)
    clear_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('clr')
    clear_btn.click()
    sleep(2)
    print(list1)
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Have to tried with explicit wait after clicking on the search? Does your code execute atleast one try block successfully?

Comment: @supputuri No I used a print statement under the first try and it printed. then under the elm_results and nothing prints

Comment: I tried WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,("span.flex[ng-bind=' .... same result.

Comment: Try adding `EC.presence_of_element_located` in each try block. I am sure either the script is not waiting for some element to be present or the locators might need to revisited.

Comment: `elm_result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.flex[ng- 
        bind='(lbecord.F)']").text` there is a typo in the css try with `span.flex[ng-bind^='(LB.record.F']`

Comment: That would make sense. Thats why when I use the print statement after elm_result its going to the except block and printing[]? correct? So i should use span.flex[ng-bind^=' .... how do I end the selector by '] or etc? Is there any documentation on this? Also is there a quick way to output this to a csv file with headers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197531/discussion-between-supputuri-and-mike-j).