# Using Selenium in Python, how do I click a link that is different for each item in a list?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, tags

Iam using selenium in python and trying click on a link however its different for every item in a list. How do I click the link below if changes each hour?

```
<td class="name table-participant" colspan="2"><a 
href="/basketball/europe/euroleague/lyon-villeurbanne-alba-berlin- 
vcATLt3c/"><span class="bold">Lyon-Villeurbanne</span> - Alba 
Berlin</a></td>

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com")

elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text('BASKETBALL')
elem.click()
sleep(2)
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Europe')
elem1.click()
sleep(2)
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Euroleague')
elem2.click()
sleep(2)
elem3 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('RESULTS')
elem3.click()
sleep(2)

elem4 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("td/a href[contains(text(), '/basketball/europe/euroleague/')]")
#WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH("//li[contains(., '/basketball/europe/euroleague/')"))))
elem4.click()
```

Comment: You have to make your selection criteria more stable. For example, you can use  [XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17329641/10650942) to get a link by its text.

Comment: @AndreySemakin driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(), '/basketball/europe/euroleague/')]") .... I need something more specific too many links like this

Comment: How do you choose correct link when you use the website via browser?

Comment: @devlops_s the code you posted works as expected and returns you a list of elements to `elem4` variable. Which link exactly do you need? First, any or some particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following CSS selector to get all the elements in result table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"BASKETBALL"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Europe"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Euroleague"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"RESULTS"))).click()

#To get all the elements
allelements=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td.name.table-participant >a[href^='/basketball/europe/euroleague/']")))

for i in range(len(allelements)):

    #To avoid stale exceptions
    allelements = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.name.table-participant >a[href^='/basketball/europe/euroleague/']")))
    print(allelements[i].text)
    #To avoid ElementClickInterceptedException 
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",  allelements[i])
    #Perform your opearions
    driver.back()
```

Comment: after getting into page Iam looking to click on a tab ......<li class=" active" style="display: block;"><span class="topleft_corner"></span><span class="topright_corner"></span><strong><span>Asian Handicap</span></strong></li> ........... ebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"Asian Handicap"))).click()     ................is giving me a error

Comment: your css selector is wrong.try use following XPATH  `WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Asian Handicap']"))).click()`

Comment: Are you sure that element present on the page.It would be great if you could post a new question and post your workflow as well.Thanks

Comment: this is the page issue iam facing how loop pages. Maybe you could help..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471668/how-to-fix-a-page-loop-in-python-during-webscrapping?noredirect=1#comment105123429_59471668